# Mobile IOS Application to Server interaction design?

Tags: server, mobile, search-engine

I've built a set of what will be server-side programs in python. Essentially they crawl the net and index news articles.

The iOS mobile application will be what the user interacts with. So it needs to query the server somehow to get the results back. I.e. if the user types in 'Google' or 'GOOG' it will return news articles concerning Google.

I'm assuming the server needs to be sent the query, the server produces the results by going over the hosted data and then sends it back, but how does it all work?

I'm looking for a set of basic design principles for this sort of thing. Although if you would like to give a breakdown that would be even better.

Comment: Using HTTP/web technology for this kind of thing is very popular, so you can look at web frameworks (rails, jsp, node.js etc etc).  Authentication is usually something you have to think about/read up on too.  You also need to think about scale.  If you're only expecting a few requests a day then the design considerations are quite different form thousands of requests per minute.